# Restricting open dialog box to certain files using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, input

When uploading photos and videos, the open dialog box should default to file suffixes that are relevant. e,d when i uploading images, it should show only file with extension .jpeg, jpg, gif, png, bmp etc. And same with videos..

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with JavaScript (possibly for security reasons). The "open file" dialog is handled by the browser's `<input type="file">` control and not by JS code.

If it's an absolute necessity, consider a Java or Flash uploader applet - you'd have much more control over the UI there.